# MarshalAs Attribute not supported in PCL for "Windows Phone Silverlight"?

Tags: silverlight, portable-class-library

When I add the "Windows Phone Silverlight 8 (or 8.1)" target to my portable class library, the compiler flags MarshalAs:
error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MarshalAs' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

According to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshalasattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) it is supported on WP Silverlight and in PCL.

Am I missing something here or is it really not available?

P.S.: Targeting Silverlight 5 shows the same problem...

Comment: Take a step back; what are you trying to marshal?

Comment: This is needed for file structures.

Comment: BTW, if you switch the docs to .NET Framework  4.5, it's clearly supported:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshalasattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: It seems that this is simply missing in the portable class target for Silverlight.
I'm axing the Marshal Stuff altogether and use a different approach.